# Hibernate @OneToOne with updatable = false still updating

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have an hibernate managed entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

// (omitted useless details)

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", updatable = false)
private Child child;

// (omitted useless details)
}
```

--

```
@Entity
public class Child {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
// (omitted rest...this is a POJO)
}
```

Since the responsibility of the update for `Child` is managed elsewhere, my goal is to simply *not* update child when the parent is saved.  Unfortunately, this `updatable = false` on the `@JoinColumn` appears to be getting ignored, saving any changes made to both parent and child.

How can I achieve only saving the parent in a one to one relationship?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Clarification, the Child class is an `@Entity` as well, but a simple POJO. The relationship between Parent and Child is unidirectional from the parent.

Comment: have you tried to set `insertable` attribute to `false` in `JoinColumn` annotation?

Comment: Yep, i added them both as a test and still no dice. Child is still updated :(

Comment: The relationship which Parent and Child possess is UniDirectional or BiDirectional? Can you update the code of chie also?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari The relationship is unidirectional from the parent.  I've added code for child, but its just a POJO -- nothing special there.

Comment: Just to be clear: fields on the child are getting persisted when you save the parent?

Comment: @dcsohl Yes, the both child and parent are getting persisted. The goal is to save just the parent.

Comment: `updatable = false` would prevent you from changing *which* child is being pointed to, not prevent you from cascading changes to the child's fields. (Rather like a variable being made `final`.) But ... I don't see any `cascade` options set in your code, so this may not be much help to you.

Comment: @dcsohl I had actually tried that as well no combination of cascade and updatable/insertable seemed to do the trick.  Feels like there's something simple I'm missing here :(

Comment: How are you inserting/updating the value in child_id filed of Parent class when you are first saving the entity?

Comment: @OnResolve then, is it possible if when you trying to save the parent, you set the child into `null` rather than referring to real entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this for quite a while and looking at the documentation for @JoinColumn annotation and the updatable/insertable properties it says...

"(Optional) Whether the **column is included** in SQL UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider."

What this means is setting updatable = false will only prevent the foreign key from being updated (column is included).  When you save the parent entity it will also save all child entities attached to the object.

This means that any child properties that are attached to the parent entity when you save will also be persisted.  This brings another issue to light if someone else may have updated this child entity, but because you are saving the parent entity with the child entity attached to it, you will un-knowingly overwrite any changes made to the child object.

Solution:

AFAIK the only way to resolve this is to be diligent about the object you save, unless you really need to be saving/updating the child entities don't.  Keep your objects self contained, this is the downfalls of lazy/eager loaded properties and saving that same object graph.  You could also do like another poster said and set the child entity to null before the save to prevent any updates, but can easily be missed.

If you are OK with saving the entire object tree (parent and children entities) you could add a property that utilizes the @Version attribute to introduce optimistic concurrency.  This way if any entity was updated by someone else and you are trying to save an old version it will fail.

```
@Version
@Column(name=”version”)
private long version;
public long getVersion() { return version; }
```